# CodeIgniter, Having problems locating thumbnail image after resize on Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, codeigniter-2

I am having problems with generating thumbnail image on Amazon EC2.

It works perfectly fine on my local machine, the error occurs when I deployed it to Amazon EC2

The Error/Warning is as I try to upload it the thumbnail to Amazon S3 and the original image upload just fine.

```
Severity: User Warning
Message:  S3::inputFile(): Unable to open input file: /tmp/file_name_thumb.jpg
Filename: libraries/S3.php
Line Number: 263
```

The Code for my Controller is

```
//This is the config for first image
$config['upload_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir(); // I tried switching this to '/tmp';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '500';
$config['max_width'] = '0';
$config['max_height'] = '0';
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->load->library('image_lib');

//Then I do upload
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

// 2nd Config for resize
$config = array(
   'source_image'   => $data['upload_data']['full_path'], //path of the uploaded image
   'new_image'      => sys_get_temp_dir(), //path to target resize, I tried switching this to '/tmp' also ;
   'create_thumb'   => true,
   'maintain_ratio' => true,
   'width'          => 300,
   'height'         => 300,
   'master_dim'     => 'width',);

$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->resize();

// Get the path of thumbnail
$fileTempThumbName = sys_get_temp_dir().'/'.$data['upload_data']['raw_name'].'_thumb'.$data['upload_data']['file_ext']; // I also tried replacing the sys_get_temp_dir() with '/tmp'.
```

the $fileTempThumbName is the paramaters I put into

```
$this->s3->putObject($this->s3->inputFile($fileTempThumbName, false),$bucket,$name,$array(),$array())
```

My local is running on OSX 10.8.2 with XAMPP and PHP Version 5.3.1
My CodeIgniter is version 2.1.3 with [Amazon S3 PHP Class 0.4.0](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class)

I have also chmod 777 the tmp folder on my Amazon EC2 instance.

The resized image is just not there when I checked the tmp folder.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Silly me, after checking the phpinfo() Amazon EC2 does not have GD installed, After Installing it trough terminal, it works just fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I did not have GD Installed on Amazon EC2.

After Installing it, everything works quite well.